# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 10-13: invalid data

Tags: android, python, utf-8, decode

I use SL4A to run python scripts on android. I have a file in a server which is a .csv file and contain strings. There are lines, one line content is like this:

```
1;ABC Budaörs;47.472518;19.059895
```

I try to make a toast on my android mobile phone, but I get the following error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 10-13: invalid data
```

I guess that python can't decode the caharacter: `ö`. Why? Isn't it in utf-8 when I download the file?

Here is my code:

```
f = urllib.urlopen(URL);
for line in f:
     droid.makeToast(line)
```

Anyway, if I just try to print to the console the `1;ABC Budaörs;47.472518;19.059895` line I get the following result:

```
1;ABC Buda�rs;47.472518;19.059895
```

What is this � character?

Thanks for the answers!!

Answer (score 1):

> �  is **[replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29#Replacement_character)** (often a black diamond with a white question mark) is a symbol found in the Unicode standard at codepoint `U+FFFD` in the Specials table. It is used to indicate problems when a system is not able to render a stream of data to a correct symbol.

and your error is because of that Your string doesn't actually contain `utf-8` it contains some other encoding. Figure out what that encoding is and use it for encoding!

Comment: And how can I figure out? I try to check the content-type from the header, but it just contains text/plain.

Comment: @Tamás you sont need to check the type just based on your language you can search and find the proper encoding for that , and then decode your string !

Comment: I solved my problem, just added f.read().decode("latin-1) and now it is working.

Comment: @Tamás nice ,im glad  !so `latin-1` is what you wont !

Answer (score 0):

The csv file is in something like iso-8859-1 or windows-1252.

You can use iconv to convert it to utf-8 (available free on windows and unix)

If you look at the file in a hex editor you will probably find one byte with the high bit set at the location rather than two.